# Should I seek the services of a lawyer when marrying my girlfriend who is on a J1 student visa?

Tags: immigration, visa

We are planning on getting married. I am a US citizen and she is a student here on a J1 visa from Germany. She does not have a residency requirement. We have been together nearly 2.5 years and have pictures together and with our families to back up any claims.

Lawyers will cost around 400 dollars just for a consultation. I am wondering if this is a super tricky area of the law or we should be able to handle it by ourselves?

Comment: I have no idea why you would need a lawyer to get married unless you want a prenuptial agreement. Clarify your requirements and concerns.

Comment: Are you asking about seeking legal advice in connection with marrying her, or in connection with applying for a green card for her?  Or are you planning to move with her to the EU?

Answer (score 1):

Congrats. This is a better question for expats.

But basically you’d get married, file an I-130 marriage petition, and once that is given, file for a green card.

It’ll cost you at least a thousand in filing fees, so you could hire a lawyer to help you make sure your paperwork is correct.